# generic mysql reference to each attribute

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm looking for a good approach to have a generic way to make references to each attribute of each entity.

Example is I have N entities with N attributes. So now I want to have a file upload function and a file should have a reverence to N attributes.

Is there a good an easy approach to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Easy" is a relative term. The solution is to write code. If that is easy for you, then that's the easy solution. If that's not easy for you, then there is no easy solution. If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to describe a more concrete case. I don't mean this to sound flippant — I just mean that you have asked a question that is too broad and not specific enough.

Comment: I have a web application which collects data, ~ 500 input fields. Now I want to be able to upload and reference documents for each input field. 

So each attribute can have N uploads. 

Each of these 500 input fields can also occur N times, since the data can be entered multiple times. 

Of course I don't want 500 reference tables for the data uploads.

Comment: I am only interested in approaches on how to implement the database technically.